# Can I connect a server with a 10G SFP+ port to a switch that only has 10G RJ45 ports?

Tags: networking, nic, rj45

All of our networking equipment is copper. I'm looking at buying a server but it just so happens to have a 10G SFP+ port and I'm unfamiliar with these. My understanding is that these are primarily used for fibre. After doing a bit of research it sounds like I can plug in an RJ45 transceiver into the SFF port and from there I can run copper back to the network switch. I'm just looking to get some confirmation as to whether my understanding is true. It sounds like my initial assumption that SFP is for fibre might be misguided and it is in fact agnostic to fibre/copper and you just have to pick the correct transceiver; is this correct?

Comment: And to add to the options ; in addition to fiber and RJ45 copper there is another option as well: direct attach copper DAC cables that integrate SFP ports on either end in a single unit https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twinaxial_cabling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A NIC with SFP slots is ideal because you can simple plug in whatever matches best with the specific equipment you’ll be connecting with on the other end.

When your switch provides 10G copper , select a SFP+ module for 10G base-T copper and you can establish a 10G connection with a RJ45 patch cable

The RJ45 connection makes the module a bit wider than a fiber SFP+ module which can be problematic when you need to use multiple SFP’s